# Maxima for max output

Tags: optimization

How can i find a maxpoint of equation

For example : y=3.2155x+35.85

now i want two x: x1+x2
at which y1+y2 is max.

where x1+x2=30

I want to find values of x1 and x2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of your numbers I use a and b
y1=ax1+b
y2=ax2+b
y1+y2=a(x1+x2)+b=a*30+b 
 so y1+y2 are the same für all x1, x2 with x1+x2=30

Comment: Thank you Trula

Comment: Can you also explain it for higher order function? Non-Linear